# How do I interpret this OSC message?

Tags: udp, osc

I am using a python server code to acquire the OSC data incoming at a port, say 5000, form the muse (2016) headband. The output that I receive is:

"Message from Client:b'#bundle\x00\xe0\x17\xe7\x81\x85\xe3S\xf7\x00\x00\x00(/muse/eeg\x00\x00\x00,fffff\x00\x00\x7f\xc0\x00\x00DT\xa5\x82\x7f\xc0\x00\x00\x7f\xc0\x00\x00\x7f\xc0\x00\x00'"

Can somebody tell me how to interpret this message, how to do its conversion into an understandable format (up form b'#bundle\x00 to \x00; before (muse)...)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the data from hex to decimal. A simple way to do that is turn the data into a string, remove "Message from Client:b'#bundle", and do the conversion.